# hdd script in bash - strange output

Tags: bash

Trying to check the available hdd space via a script:

```
 df -h :
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/sda3        18G  9.1G  8.7G  52% /
```

The commands are :

```
 com=`df -h | awk '{print $5}' | grep % | grep -v Use | sort -n | tail -4 | cut -d % -f1`
 echo $com
 52 74 100 100
```

I want to isolate "52" for my checks ,so :

```
    for i in ${com[@]};do
    > echo ${com[0]:0:2}
    > done
      52
      52
      52
      52
```

Ok, i managed to retrieve the correct number for my later checks ,but why the command returns the number "52" four times ??

Thanks a lot

Comment: You are not populating an array, you are just storing in a variable.

Comment: Hint: you aren't using the variable `i` in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a `bash` script for this trivial use-case. Also you are using the bunch of `awk`, `grep` commands to store output in a variable and not in an array's context.

You just need to use a simple `Awk` command,

```
df -h | awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "Use%"){ ind=i; break}} NR==2 {n=split($0, val); used=val[ind]; sub(/%/,"",used); print used}'
```

The above command first looks up the column which has the `Use%` stored in the header line and then looks up the actual value in the same column in the next row.

To use the output in a variable store the output of command substitution as below

```
used_storage=$(df -h | awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "Use%"){ ind=i; break}} NR==2 {n=split($0, val); used=val[ind]; sub(/%/,"",used); print used}')
echo "$used_storage"
```